# c# long running task in background

Tags: c#, service, mediatr

We have a function app that build a large json payload(+- 2000 lines) everyday and posts it to the api to be mapped and saved into a database.

We are using cqrs with mediatr and it seems the API side takes exceptionally long to create and save all the neccesary information.

The problem we have is that the function's postasjsonasync waits for the api response and times out after a few minutes.

Any idea how to run this as a background task or just post and forget? Our API is only concerned that it received data.

Function side:

```
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"{endpoint}/api/v1.0/BatchImport/Import", json); <-- Times out waiting for API
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
```

API mediatr handle side:

```
public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreateBatchOrderCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            foreach (var importOrder in request.Payload) <-- Takes long to process all the data
            {
               await PopulateImportDataAsync(importOrder, cancellationToken);
               await CreateOrderAsync(importOrder, cancellationToken);
            }

            return Unit.Value;
        }
```

Cheers

Comment: One tiny gotcha here, instantiating `HttpClient` for every request does not scale well since this spins up a new socket and sockets do not close immediately but tend to hang around for a bit. I recommend using a singleton but this was not your question.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem we have is that the function's postasjsonasync waits for the api response and times out after a few minutes.

The *easiest* solution is going to be just increasing that timeout. If you are talking about Azure Functions, I believe you can increase the timeout to 10 minutes.

> Any idea how to run this as a background task or just post and forget? Our API is only concerned that it received data.

Any fire-and-forget solution is not going to end well; you'll end up with lost data. I recommend that you not use fire-and-forget at all, and this advice goes double as soon as you're in the cloud.

Assuming increasing the timeout isn't sufficient, your solution is to use a [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html), as described on my blog:

- Have your API place the incoming request into a durable queue.
- Have a separate backend (e.g., Azure (Durable) Function) process that request from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re on .NET Core, you could stick incoming requests into a queued background task:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks

Keep in mind this chews up resources from servicing other web requests so it will not scale well with millions of requests. This same basic principle, a message queue item and offline processing, can also be distributed across multiple services to take some of the load off the web service.